# What's a recommended way to design a db schema for multi-language website?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, languages

I'm building a website where I plan to support multiple languages. Not only via UI, but via the content too.

I have several tables where I have text columns such as "title", "name", "description", "body" and so on. What's the best way to do so? Will I have to create an additional table for each one where I have text data I want to translate? For instance:

```
articles(id)
articles_content(article_id, title, description, body, language_id)


comments(id)
comments_content(comment_id, body, language_id)
```

And thus for each table I want to translate.

Any downsides of this solution?

Is there a better and yet simpler way?

Comment: I'd have thought the db structure didn't matter (to the scope of this question) as long as each language conformed to the schema and data types provided.

Comment: It depends if you are more in the case "all articles will be available in all languages" or in the case "the amount of translations for an article will vary a lot from an article to another". The alternative method would be to put the language tag (please use RFC5646) inside the articles_content/comments_content and to have a primary composite key on (article id, language tag). Also have a look at how CMS deal with that, for example in SPIP or Drupal. Studying existing code could give you ideas...

Comment: Adding to previous comment: depends on how/how often new languages are added. If you have a table per language, adding a language means making changes in the database schema, which is better to avoid if possible. So a schema where adding a new language/translation is just adding new contents in some existing tables is a better design.

Comment: Also: do you need to link articles/comments in various languages together? Like saying content X in English is the translation of content Y in German? That has impacts on your DB design.

Comment: @Raj, This is similar to the approach we've taken for an enterprise publishing company.  However, we would have had language_id in the articles table, not articles_content.  The reason for this is that articles were not always written for all languages, and if they were, we'd just have separate articles.

Comment: As others have alluded to: the pertinent question is, "why does your code care what language the content is written in?" Are you giving users to filter content based on language? Are you auto-filtering based on HTTP request language parameters? Or are you just showing all the articles in a big list? Use the functionality to drive your  design.

Answer (score 1):

Create each "table" as a base table (with the non-translatable elements) and a translation table.  The language table will contain the primary key of the base table and the language ID.  You can then create a view layer which joins the two together for a particular language (and which the UI will drive off of).   This scenario avoids the duplicate maintenance of the non-translatable elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not having a separate multi-lingual table per base table. I would recommend having a *single* table representing a multi-lingual string and a *single* table to store the value of that string in each language.

For example, the create table statements for Postgres would be:

```
create table articles (
    id serial primary key,
    title int not null references multilingual (id),
    description int not null references multilingual (id),
    body int not null references multilingual (id)
);

create table multilingual (
    id serial primary key
);

create table string (
    id int not null references multilingual (id),
    lang lang not null, -- custom lang type defined as enum
    contents text not null,
    primary key (id, lang)
);

articles_content(article_id, title, description, body, language_id)
```

This approach involves more joins than multi-lingual table per base table, so it could degrade performance unacceptably. However, it keeps the schema simpler.